# How to make a UIApplicationMain sync

Tags: ios, synchronization

My app give me error in main function. I tried to make the NSURLConnection sync. How can I make this code in main sync?
Here is the code(main.m in the Supporting Files):

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "AppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

the code where NSUrlConnection is:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"><SOAP-ENV:Body><m:GetRoomList xmlns:m=\"http://http://port number/WebService.svc/\"><departId xsi:type=\"xsd:int\">0</departId><roomID xsi:type=\"xsd:int\">0</roomID></m:GetRoomList></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>"];

    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://port number/WebService.svc/"];

    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest= [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:30];

    NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [soapMessage length]];

    [theRequest addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [theRequest addValue: @"http://tempuri.org/WebService.svc" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
    [theRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [theRequest addValue:@"port number" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Host"];
    [theRequest setHTTPBody: [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    NSURLResponse* response = nil;
    NSData* data =[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: theRequest returningResponse: &response error: nil];
    //self.theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self startImmediately:YES];
    if (data) {
        NSLog(@"%@",data);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Failed");
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont understand what you mean by `main sync`? `UIApplicationMain()` is a blocking call itself. Also can you post the error?

Comment: Add an exception breakpoint and post the stack trace of crash.

Comment: I wrote the code in viewDidLoad with ARC.But I don't want it to release automatic. So I have to change the @autoreleasepool. Is it true or doesn't it effect?

Comment: The error disappeared.It works. I didn't remove the activity indicator view. But I still think that @autoreleasepool should not stay there.

Answer (score -1):

When iOS app crash Xcode show this line, but the error isn't here.
Show the code of your NSURLConnection